# matlab image rotation code

Tags: matlab, image-rotation, affinetransform

I'm beginner in computer vision. I'm trying to do a rotate transformation using matlab. My code is

```
I = imread('Koala.jpg');

rows = size(I, 1);
cols = size(I, 2);

deg = 45;
deg = deg * pi / 180;

C = uint8(zeros(size(I)));

mid = ceil([rows+1 cols+1] / 2);

[x1, x2] = meshgrid(1:rows, 1:cols);
M = [cos(deg) sin(deg); -sin(deg) cos(deg)];

X = bsxfun(@minus, [x1(:) x2(:)], mid) * M;
X = round(bsxfun(@plus, X, mid));

x1 = X(:, 1);
x2 = X(:, 2);
x1(x1<1) = 1;
x2(x2<1) = 1;
x1(x1>rows) = rows;
x2(x2>cols) = cols;
X = [x1(:) x2(:)];

m = 1;
for i=1:rows
    for j=1:cols
        C(X(m, 1), X(m, 2), :) = I(i, j, :);
        m = m + 1;
    end
end
```

This works but in the result there are many pixeles without values. I guess, when I do "X2 = X*M", the range of the image on the transformation it's not same of the source and many values lost

Comment: Would [`imrotate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html) be cheating?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, I would just use [`imrotate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html) to do the rotation for you.

```
out = imrotate(I, 45);
```

Otherwise, I would try to vectorize your approach and use `interp2`. You can rotate all of the pixel centers by the specified angle and then sample at these rotated point.

```
% Compute the coordinates of all pixel centers
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:size(I, 2), 1:size(I, 1));

% Compute the rotation matrix
R = [ cos(deg) sin(deg); 
     -sin(deg) cos(deg)];

xy = [x(:), y(:)];

% Compute the middle point
mid = mean(xy, 1);

% Subtract off the middle point
xy = bsxfun(@minus, xy, mid);

% Rotate all of these coordinates by the desired angle
xyrot = xy * R;

% Reshape the coordinate matrices
xy = reshape(xy, [size(x), 2]);
xyrot = reshape(xyrot, [size(x), 2]);

% Interpolate the image data at the rotated coordinates
out = interp2(xy(:,:,1), xy(:,:,2), I, xyrot(:,:,1), xyrot(:,:,2));
```